# Batch script - Starting EXE fails

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

As a personal project, I'm trying to make a very easy launcher from a batch script *(it and games folder reside in the root of `E:\`)* asking what games you wanna play, and when selected, the game is launched via:

```bat
:: my/game/path.exe
   Start "" E:/DNL/LR2/LR2.exe
```

- This works for most of my games, but for some, it doesn't work at all; I can see it executed (my games are old and the resolution changes), but it dies very quickly; if I launch the games manually, they work fine.
- I receive no errors and think the problem might be the game's path, trying both relative and absolute paths with no success; I think the problem is the script is located outside of the game folder, as placing it within the game folder and executing the `start` command works fine.

I have no clue how to make it work from outside the folder and thought about moving it within folder using `cd`; Is this the correct way to navigate to the games folder?

Answer (score 1):

If the batch file works correctly inside the folder, then you should `cd` into it, as you mentioned.

You should use `cd /D` if you `cd` into another partition, as the `/D` switch takes care of actually switching drives; if you only use `cd`, you'll have to change the partition manually:

```powershell
C:\> cd M:
M:\

# Notice how I'm still actually on C:
C:\> M:
M:\>
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides, @hextech's helpful answer, `pushd` can be used to push directories *(while `cd /d` is a good solution, it does not support UNC paths yet)*, but `pushd` will work for both UNC paths and different partitions; you can use `popd` to switch back to the past directory.

Also, the path you are using is a Linux format, with the correct Windows path being: `E:\DNL\LR2\LR2.exe`.

Comment: Windows supports paths with forward or back slashes via CLI, however I can't recall why, but do know there's an answer on Superuser that explains in detail.

Comment: Really @JW0914! Didn't knew it before.